# Why execute the return statement first instead of the Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I want to use `Parallel.ForEach` to manipulate one set and return another. But I seem to get an empty one. And There is an asynchronous method that needs to be executed in `Parallel.ForEach`.

This is a console app with .NET Core 2.2 in Windows 10.

```
public static ConcurrentBag<int> GetList()
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> result = new ConcurrentBag<int>() ;
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    Parallel.ForEach(list, async i => {
        await Task.Delay(i * 1000);
        result.Add(i * 2);
    });
    return result;
}

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    var res = GetList();
    list.AddRange(res);
    Console.WriteLine("Begging.");
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I expect {2,4,6}, but actual an empty one.

Comment: Why are you using `async` and `await Task.Delay(i*1000);`? `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't play well with `async`.

Comment: What you might want to consider doing is `return list.AsParallel(stuffhere).ToList();`. _I mean, it is pointless, but it will give you parallelism._

Comment: Don't use `Parallel.ForEach` for async code. It's meant for data parallelism **only** and can't await any tasks. What you did is fire off a bunch of tasks that may not even run before your application terminates. Parallel.ForEach has *no* way to wait for those tasks

Comment: ConcurrentBag is not a good choice either. Unlike the other concurrent collections it's a *specialized* class that uses thread-local storage to allow faster access to the thread that created an object. This means that the main thread will take longer to read the results than if you used eg a ConcurrentQueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` is the culprit. What you need to understand is that `await` is a fancy return. If the caller doesn't understand tasks, all it sees is the return. `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't expect a delegate that returns task, so it has no idea how to wait for the `await` to complete.

The `Parallel.ForEach` finishes almost as soon as it started, and long before anything gets written to `result`.

Now, `Parallel` is supposed to be used for CPU-bound operations, so this is not a problem. If you want to simulate a long-running CPU-bound operation, use `Thread.Sleep` instead of `await Task.Delay`.

As a side note, how would you parallelize a task-based operation that is I/O bound? The simplest way would be something like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(YourAsyncOperation));
```

Where `YourAsyncOperation` is an async method returning `Task`, which can use `Task.Delay` as much as you want. The main problem with this simple approach is that you *must* be sure that `YourAsyncOperation` actually does an `await`, soon, and ideally doesn't use a synchronization context. In the worst case, all of the calls are going to be serialized. Well, really, in the absolute worst case, you get a deadlock, but... :)